# Calculating the difference between 2 days in tkinter gui takes a lot of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I have the following code that calculates the difference between `start_date` & `end_date`:

```
from tkinter import *
import math
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
#frame.pack()

label1 = Label(root, text="Peak")
label1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
label2 = Label(root, text="Base")
label2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
label3 = Label(root, text="Total Consumption")
label3.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
label4 = Label(root, text="Start day in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
label4.grid(row=3, sticky=E)
label5 = Label(root, text="End day in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
label5.grid(row=4, sticky=E)
label6 = Label(root, text="Diff in days (n)")
label6.grid(row=5, sticky=E)

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2 = Entry(root)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
entry3 = Entry(root)
entry3.grid(row=2, column=1)
entry4 = Entry(root)
entry4.grid(row=3, column=1)
entry5 = Entry(root)
entry5.grid(row=4, column=1)
entry6 = Entry(root)
entry6.grid(row=5, column=1)

def date_checker():
    try:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(entry4.get(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end_date = datetime.strptime(entry5.get(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq = 'S').tolist()
        dates = pd.Series(dates)
        dates_diff = abs((end_date - start_date).days)
        dates = dates.iloc[:-1]
        label = Label(root, text = 'Dates accepted!')
        label.grid(row=6, column=1)
        entry6.delete(0, END)
        entry6.insert(0, dates_diff)
    except ValueError:
        label2 = Label(root, text = 'Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
        label2.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)
        raise ValueError("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")

button1 = Button(root, text='Dates Checker', command = date_checker)
button1.grid(row=6, column=4)
button2 = Button(root, text='Generate Graph')
button2.grid(row=7, column=4)
button3 = Button(root, text='Quit', command = root.quit)
button3.grid(row=8, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

What this code does is that it takes `start_date` & `end_date` from the user and calculates the difference between the two dates. This code works absolutely fine.

But when I input `start_date` as `2018-01-01 00:00:00` & `end_date` as `2018-12-31 00:00:00`, it takes forever to calculate and give the output.

Is there a way the above code, or the `date_checker` function in particular, be optimized so that it takes less time?

Comment: problem is not calcultion but `pd.date_range().tol_list()` etc. which needs time to generate all data. If you don't use this dataframe then remove it and you get result at once.

Comment: You're generating a list of every second present in a year. That's 60*60*24*365 which is about 31 million elements in a list. Why are you surprised that it takes a long time?

Comment: Please reduce this down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with calculating a date, we don't need labels and entries for a bunch of unrelated items. This doesn't even seem to have anything to do with tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have any use for `dates`, but this is the part that is costing you time. If you change `data_checker()` to the code below, calculating the days is almost instant.

```
def date_checker():
    try:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(entry4.get(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end_date = datetime.strptime(entry5.get(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        dates_diff = abs((end_date - start_date).days)
        label = Label(root, text = 'Dates accepted!')
        label.grid(row=6, column=1)
        entry6.delete(0, END)
        entry6.insert(0, dates_diff)
    except ValueError:
        label2 = Label(root, text = 'Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
        label2.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)
        raise ValueError("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")
```

**EDIT:**

If you need the `dates` Series, you probably don't actually need the timerange in seconds. Changing for example your daterange from seconds to hour will save you lots of time:

With seconds:

```
%timeit date_checker('2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-12-31 23:59:59')
2min 59s ± 10.3 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

With hours:

```
%timeit date_checker('2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-12-31 23:59:59')
52.2 ms ± 5.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I have to actually use the `dates` df in the next step which is plotting a graph using matplotlib.

Comment: But do you really need a daterange with seconds (31 million elements as ChatterOne mentioned)? I added the difference in processing time between seconds and hours.